# Cambiar Css de botón de libreria por defecto

Tags: php, css, botón

Alguien sabe como se puede cambiar el nombre al botón ‘Seleccionar archivo’ y ‘Ningún archivo seleccionado’ que aparece en la siguiente imagen?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece que es un botón que viene por defecto de googleapis.com. No consigo cambiarle el nombre, me podríais ayudar? Gracias.

Este es el código que utiliza:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div align="center">
        <label class="selectCSV">Select the CSV file:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_exercises" value="Import" class="btn btn-info" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: En realidad el botón `type="file"` es un estándar de HTML, y cada navegador lo interpreta de diferentes maneras. No es posible cambiar este comportamiento nativo con reglas sencillas, todas las soluciones que te puedan brindar van a ser [_"hacks"_ de código](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163667/how-to-rename-html-browse-button-of-an-input-type-file) intentando burlar el normal comportamiendo de [las reglas del W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/input.file.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El texto pertenece al `<label>` y el `input type="file"`es invisible. Hay una cosa llamada "El apaño de la etiqueta `<label>`". Puedes vincular una etiqueta `<label>` con un elemento de `<input>` si el valor del atributo `for` de `<label>` tiene que el mismo valor que atributo `id` del `<input>`.

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="boton" />
<label class="selectCSV"  for="boton">El texto que tu quieres:</label>
```

Si los vinculas puedes hacer click en el `<label>` para activar el `<input>`. Sabiendo esto puedes dar los estilos que tu quieras al `<label>` y esconder el `<input>`.

Ahora lo que falta es cambiar el texto del label

```css
.selectCSV {
  color: white;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  background-color: tomato;
  display: block;
  width: 9em;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="file"] {
  width: 0.1px;
  height: 0.1px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div align="center">
        
        <input type="file" name="file" id="boton" />
        <label class="selectCSV"  for="boton">El texto que tu quieres</label>
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_exercises" value="Import" class="btn btn-info" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hay que tener en cuenta que al ocultar el input type file, el usuario no va a saber si el archivo que seleccionó es el correcto, o si quedó siquiera seleccionado, pues esta información también estará oculta.